# error creating table on my DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a table that references another table in my db however I am receiving this error.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UInt32 PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(20), handle VARCHAR(20), countryName VARCHAR(20' at line 1
```

I have had a look at error #1064 on the [mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html) refrence page but its abit of a vuage error just giving the outline of its structure.

```
 Error: 1064 SQLSTATE: 42000 (ER_PARSE_ERROR)

Message: %s near '%s' at line %d
```

this is the code I have tried to execute

```
CREATE TABLE User (userID UInt32 PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(20), handle VARCHAR(20), countryName VARCHAR(20) references Countries(SID))engine=innodb;
```

Countries table has already been created, so I am not entirely sure what is causing the problem

any help would be greatly appreciated.

added not this is how I have defined countries

```
CREATE TABLE Countries (countryName VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY)engine=innodb;
```

Comment: Could it be that User is a reserved keyword?

Comment: hrmmm.. it could be.. i wouldnt know dont do alot of sql just playing around with an idea... but by your tone I am guessing that it is.. which would make sense... lol im going to go try using a different table name... LOL

Comment: hrmm.. nope I have changed the table name and am still suffering from the same problem..

Comment: Could you show the table definition of Countries, please? Is Countries.SID a VARCHAR(20)?

Comment: **CREATE TABLE Countries (countryName VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY)engine=innodb;**

Comment: It looks like your constraint is referencing "SID", but it should reference "countryName"

Comment: I have changed this and am still getting the same error.. I am thinking its the way I have declared one of the values... or something else.. but I cannot see where the mistake might be as I have very little experiance with sql :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED response:

Moving the constraint definition out of the table definition helped isolate the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE User(
   userID UInt32 PRIMARY KEY
  ,name VARCHAR(20)
  ,handle VARCHAR(20)
  ,countryName VARCHAR(20)
)engine=innodb;


ALTER TABLE user ADD CONSTRAINT user_country_name_fk FOREIGN KEY(countryName) REFERENCES Countries(SID);
```

Table creation failure was caused by the use of the `UInt32` data type. Changed to `int`, table creation succeeded.

Foreign key constraint was referring to the wrong column in `Countries`. It was referring to `SID` but needed to refer to `countryName`.

Comment: okay I will try it out.. im not sure what the difference is between this an inline however.

Comment: okay will try this now.. tried the first one and ran into problems.. but will try your second solution quickly.

Comment: ah so it seems even without the FK I am getting errors.. **Error
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE USER( userID UInt32 PRIMARY KEY , name VARCHAR( 20 ) , handle VARCHAR( 20 ) , countryName VARCHAR( 20 ) ) ENGINE = INNODB

MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UInt32 PRIMARY KEY
  ,name VARCHAR(20)
  ,handle VARCHAR(20)
  ,countryName V' at line 2 **

Comment: See comment on question. According to the Countries definition, your constraint should reference "countryName" rather than "SID".

Comment: okay Glenn will try that now as well.. however I am getting the error even without the constraints in there as you can see in my last comment on your answer..

Comment: On sqlfiddle, it fails for me with "UInt32". If I change "UInt32" to "int", it works.  I'm not familiar with mysql, and don't know the type.

Comment: hrmm... okay.. I dont suppose it matters if its signed or unsigned.. but how big is an int.. or can i define int32?

Comment: okay int worked for me also.. I am jut woundering the ramifications of it however.. I am not sure how big or small this value is now.. I dont mind the fact its signed or unsigned but just would like to know what size it is.. lol thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry can't help there. Need to check the manuals for type information.

Comment: An int is 4 bytes so it is what you were looking for. Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html.

Comment: @JeffSiver thanks for the link :P Glenn thanks for the help :) much appreciated, if you would like to update your answer just explaining that it was a change from Uint32 to int.. then ill accept the answer :) thanks again